# LWGL // reconstruct position in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, shader, lwjgl, depth, zbuffer

I have the correct inverse projection matrix. But nothing seem to be right!
The reconstructed position ist totally deformed und the z-Value ist much to small? Anyone a suggestion?

```
vec3 calculatePosition(vec2 coord, float depth)
{ 
vec4 clipSpaceLocation;
clipSpaceLocation.x = coord.x * 2.0 - 1.0;
clipSpaceLocation.y = coord.y * 2.0 - 1.0;
clipSpaceLocation.z = depth * 2.0 - 1.0;
clipSpaceLocation.w = 1.0;
vec4 homogenousPosition = uProjectionInverse * clipSpaceLocation;

return homogenousPosition.xyz / homogenousPosition.w;
}
```

the z-Value is round about -0,001; Why that?

coord und depth is:

```
vec2 coord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / width, gl_FragCoord.y / height);
float currentDepth = texture(depthBuffer, coord).r;
```

I have to implement SSAO for university and i use Eclipse and Java with the lwjgl-plugin.
Please i need help. I got less than one week.

EDIT:
I have tried this now... but still not lenearized:

```
float camera_space_z_from_depth(sampler2D depthbuffer, vec2 uv) {
    float depth = texture(depthbuffer, uv).x;
    return (2 * uNearPlane) / (uFarPlane + uNearPlane - depth * (uFarPlane -       uNearPlane));
}

vec3 calculatePosition(vec2 coord, float depth)
{   
    vec4 clipSpaceLocation;
    clipSpaceLocation.x = coord.x * 2.0 - 1.0;
    clipSpaceLocation.y = coord.y * 2.0 - 1.0;
    clipSpaceLocation.z = depth * 2.0 - 1.0;
    clipSpaceLocation.w = 1.0;
   vec4 homogenousPosition = uProjectionInverse * clipSpaceLocation;

   return homogenousPosition.xyz / homogenousPosition.w;
}
vec3 getPosition(vec2 coord){
    float currentDepth = camera_space_z_from_depth(depthBuffer,coord);  
    vec3 position = calculatePosition(coord, currentDepth);
    return position;
}
```

Comment: The original code (not the edit) looks OK so far. The linearization in the edit does not really make sense assuming your depth render pass just used the normal z coordinate. To me this looks like there is an issue with either `uProjectionInverse` or - and this would be my first guess - the depth texture (or the depth rende rpass itself). Is the `near` value for your projection `0.001` by any chance? If so, it looks like the depth value you are trying to unproject is just 0 at all points.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I suppose you need to linearize your depth value, like said here:</s>

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space

Just try this.

```
float camera_space_z_from_depth(sampler2D depthbuffer, vec2 uv) {
    const float depth = texture(depthbuffer, uv).x;
    return ( camera_near / (camera_far - depth * (camera_far - camera_near)) ) * camera_far;
}
```

EDIT:

Try that. Variable meaning should be self explanatory (no need for linearization) :)

```
vec3 GetPosition(vec2 fragmentCoordinates, float depth)
{
    vec3 normalizedDeviceCoordinatesPosition;
    normalizedDeviceCoordinatesPosition.xy = (2.0 * fragmentCoordinates) / uScreenSize - 1;
    normalizedDeviceCoordinatesPosition.z = 2.0 * depth - 1.0;

    vec4 clipSpacePosition;
    clipSpacePosition.w = uProjection[3][2] / (normalizedDeviceCoordinatesPosition.z - (uProjection[2][2] / uProjection[2][3]));
    clipSpacePosition.xyz = normalizedDeviceCoordinatesPosition * clipSpacePosition.w;

    vec4 eyePosition = uInverseProjection * clipSpacePosition;

    return eyePosition.xyz / eyePosition.w;
}
```

Note: So far I'm assuming your depth texture is a GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and is attached to the framebuffer as a GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT.

I.e.:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mDepthTextureId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, mrScreenWidth, mrScreenHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mDepthTextureId, 0);
```

Comment: Notice that just for testing this out you can hard-code the camera_near and camera_far variables used in the code snippet!

Comment: Just to make sure, uScreenSize would be a vec2 equivalent to what you'd have with vec2(width, height) in your code snippet ;)

Comment: Note that part of my code is just like yours... the real difference is the computation in clipSpacePosition.w